# Quartz type lib has data conversion issues under .net4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, quartz

I'm trying to use Quartz in a new Project with windows10 and .net4. I've added "Windows\system32\quartz.dll" to may Project and I can play audio files without a problem.

The problem arises when using the "Owner" property in order to show video, I get a conversión error in runtime. This is the sample code:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
FilgraphManagerClass graphManager = new QuartzTypeLib.FilgraphManagerClass();
graphManager.Owner = panel.Handle.ToInt32(); 
graphManager.RenderFile(@"c:\temp\simple.mp4");
```

This is the error message:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified Cast is not valid

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: I get this excepiton: System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.' (Specified conversión is not valid) when assigning the Owner property.